# UITableViewCell UILineBreakMode when cell.numberOfLines is 0

Tags: iphone, uitableview

By default, `UILineBreakMode` in a `UITableViewCell` is `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`. Does this change when I set `[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Then come back with some code that you've tried and a question about how to do what you require if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: yes it changed to UILineBreakModeWordWrap.

Comment: I have obtained UILineBreakModeWordWrap too.